# How can I tell if a multi dimensional array has not been assigned to?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, initialization

If I have two arrays likes this:

```
short** x;
short** y = functionThatReturnsAnArray();
```

In this situation `sizeof(x) == sizeof(y)`.
Both are 4, I believe that this is because the outer array is simply an array of pointers and therefore doesn't actually have any RAM allocated to it.

How can I find out that x has not been assigned a value?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: The size of `x` and `y` will always be `4` in your case even if they do have memory allocated to them, because `sizeof` just returns the size of its argument, and the size of a pointer is always `4` (in your case) no matter what it points to.

Comment: delnan - Not assigned to

Comment: ... in C, there's no way to tell how many things a pointer is pointing to, right? You need to also pass the number of elements in the store as metadata along with the pointer.

Comment: @user940516 usually people will assign a pointer the value `NULL` (which is 0) to indicate that it doesn't point to anything. You should do `short** x = NULL`, then to check if you have set it to point to anything, do `if (x != NULL) // is assigned`

Comment: @user940516: You should edit your answer to make that clear to anyone just reading the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment in your original post, what you mean is whether you can tell if a value has been assigned to a variable.  We call that *initialization*. When a value hasn't been stored to a variable it's *uninitialized*, and that's bad, because you never know what might be in there, and no, you cannot check whether it has been initialized, so initialize it when you declare it.

---

`sizeof(x) == sizeof(y)` because they're declared as the same type (`short**`); their contents don't matter (`sizeof` is actually determined by the compiler, so it often can't know what's in it).

If you want to know whether the memory areas that each point to are zero, you'll need to do it manually (and you need to know how long each array is):

```
int x_empty = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < x_length_d1 && x_empty; i++) {
    if(x[i] == NULL) {
        // Handle a missing row however you want.
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < x_length_d2 && x_empty; j++) {
        if(x[i][j] != 0) x_empty = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the clarification on terminology, very useful beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

The `sizeof` returns the size of `short**` (pointer to pointer to short) which appears to be 4 bytes in your system. If you allocate memory, you should know how many bytes have you allocated, and pass this value as well.

For example:

```
size_t size_allocated = 0;
short** y = functionThatReturnsAnArray(&size_allocated);
```

---

```
short ** functionThatReturnsAnArray(size_t * size) {
    short ** buff;
    size_t size_to_allocate = 5 * sizeof(short *);
    buff = malloc(size_to_allocate);
    if (!buff) {
        *size = size_to_allocate;
    }
    else {
        *size = 0;
    }
    return buff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot check if a variable has been assigned to. The value of an uninitialized variable is undefined IIRC. According to [Assigning pointer to uninitialized variable changes it value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7468166/726361) (found by Seth Carnegie), even accessing it causes undefined behaviour.

The solution? Explicitly assign a sentinel value and check for that. For pointers, `NULL` usually makes sense.

Comment: Looking at the value of an un-assigned variable isn't UB is it?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: As I indicated, I'm not 100% sure. A reference would be great. Perhaps it's simply a terminology mixup on my part? I'd be *very* surprised if the standard guaranteed the value of an uninitialized (local, non-`static`) variable, but perhaps it doesn't fit the exact definition of UB.

Comment: no it definitely doesn't guarantee the value of an uninitialised variable, but apparently you're right, it is called UB according to http://stackoverflow.com/q/7468166/726361 , which was written by Als whom I trust about things like this. I thought it would be implementation-defined behaviour, but apparently not. +1

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Kudos for digging that up. I've taken the liberty to incorporate it in my answer.